# Unity 2D: Подсчет колличества комнат, счётчик пройденных комнат (закрыт)

Tags: разработка-игр, room, counter, procedural-generation

В моей игре в стиле Top Down Shooter есть комнаты (каждая комната - отдельный префаб), и при каждом запуске игры их спавнится разное количество. Мне нужно, чтобы подсчитывалось общее количество комнат. Я думал о том, чтобы сделать счётчик, проверяющий, какое колличество комнат прошёл игрок. Когда игрок заходит в комнату, счётчик увеличивается на 1. Когда игрок побывает во всех комнатах (колличество пройденных комнат = общее количество комнат), будет происходить событие. Важно подметить, что счётчик должен увеличиваться только единожды за одну комнату, то есть, если вы прошли комнату *а* до этого, и это прибавилось к счётчику пройденных комнат, то при прохождении этой же комнаты *а* во второй раз очко прибавлятся уже не будет. Но я не знаю, как всё это реализовать. Если вы чего то не поняли, то спрашивайте, я поясню. Могу отправить скрипты и скриншоты. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

**Способ, в котором игрок входит в комнату и считается кол-во комнат:**

Можно добавить тригер(Box collider2D), а в коде же сделать подобное условие:

```
private void AddPoint()
{
    point++;
    if (point > 10) // Например, если 10 комнат
    {
       // Выполнять ваше условие
    }

}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
 {
     if (other.gameObject.tag == "newRoom") // Или other.gameObject.name
     {
         AddPoint();
         Destroy(other.gameObject);
     }
}
```

Данный код является примером. В условии, где имеется цифра 10 - можно брать количество комнат из скрипта, который и спавнит комнаты

Comment: Точно, спасибо огромное. А как только изначально в скрипте посчитать колличество комнат? Их спавнится рандомное колличество, и вот у меня и была ещё эта проблема. Есть идеи, что можно сделать? А по поводу тега "newRoom", я полагаю, он будет стоять у BoxCollider2D, и когда перс касается коллайдера, прибавляется point и BoxCollider2D уничтожается?

Comment: Подсказать про подсчёт кол-ва комнат я не могу, так как отсутствует код спавна. Могу предложить создать переменную, и её увеличивать при instantiate (int++). После, эту переменную подстраивать в другой скрипт(вместо 10, в условии)
`А по поводу тега "newRoom"` вы всё верно поняли.
Если ответ вам помог - не забудьте нажать на галочку